# Incorrectly Reading a Column Containing Lists in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, list

I have a pandas data frame containing a column with a list that I am reading from a CSV. For example, the column in the CSV appears like so:

```
ColName2007
=============
['org1', 'org2']
['org2', 'org3']
...
```

So, when I read this column into Pandas, each entry of the columns is treated as a string, rather than a list of strings.

`df['ColName2007'][0]` returns `"['org1', 'org2']"`. **Notice this is being stored as a string, not a list of strings.**

I want to be able to perform list operations on this data. What is a good way to quickly and efficiently convert this column of strings into a column of lists that contain strings?

Comment: Apply `literal_eval` method from `ast` package as  `df["ColName2007"] = df["ColName2007"].apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [`strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html)/[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) :

```
df['ColName2007']= df['ColName2007'].str.strip("[]").str.split(",")
```

Otherwise, you can apply an [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as suggested by @Bjay Regmi in the comments.

```
import ast

df["ColName2007"] = df["ColName2007"].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```